# JavaFX - load FXML-file without FXLoader

Tags: javafx, fxmlloader

I am experementing with the "new" JavaFX and it worked very well.

Now I am at a point which is incomprehensible for me. I have a Controller for my View and I want to load my Controller from a main-method so the controller can load a view or do whatever it likes.

My problem ist, that I have to load my FXML-File with the `FXMLLoader.load()` method. The FXMLLoader himselfe loads the controller. So in fact, with my method I will load the controller two times: I load the controller with `XController xcontroller = new XController();` and inside that controller I load te view with the `FXMLLoader.load()` which will load the controller again.

do I have to use `FXMLLoader` or can I let my controller load the view with an other method?

*edit* I want to use the Presentation-Abstraction-Control (PAC) Pattern (variation of MVC), that's why I think it's importand to let the controller load the View.

the main class

```
    public class Main extends Application
    {

        Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage)
        {
            LoginController loginController = null;
            try
            {
                loginController = new LoginController();
                loginController.loadSceneInto(primaryStage);

                primaryStage.show();
            }
            .......


        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

the controller

```
    public class LoginController
    {

        .....
        public void loadSceneInto(Stage stage) throws IOException
        {
            this.stage  = stage;
            Scene scene = null;
            Pane  root  = null;

            try
            {
                root = FXMLLoader.load(
                        getClass().getResource(
                                this.initialView.getPath()
                        )
                );

                scene = new Scene(root, initialWidth, initialHeight);
                this.stage.setTitle(this.stageTitle);
                this.stage.setScene(scene);

                this.centralizeStage();
            }
            .....
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. There is no need (and pretty much no use) for loading a controller without an associated view, and you simply cannot load a view from the `main` method, because the JavaFX toolkit has not been initialized at that point. The only way you can load the UI defined in the FXML file is via a `FXMLLoader`. You don't have to let the `FXMLLoader` instantiate the controller: you can instantiate it yourself and pass it to the `FXMLLoader` prior to loading the FXML (but creating it in `main` is still pointless: you can't access the `FXMLLoader` there).

Comment: I recommend you [edit] the question and provide some code so that you can clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't know the PAC pattern (all these things are just variants of MVC, right?): maybe you can modify [this approach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components) (in which the controller is loading the view) to get to what you want.

Comment: @James_D shure I can load everything with one simple ```FXMLLoader.load(...)``` from the main method. Beause the FXML-File wil then initialize the Controller from his ```fx:controller=...``` attribute

Comment: So set the controller manually.

Comment: @James_D thank you for the Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, instead of

```
    root = FXMLLoader.load(
            getClass().getResource(
                    this.initialView.getPath()
            )
    );
```

Just do

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
    getClass().getResource(this.initialView.getPath());
);
loader.setController(this);
root = loader.load();
```

You will need to remove the `fx:controller` attribute from the FXML file for this to work.

Comment: that sounds great, I will try that :)